# How to unzip a file using git bash (Windows)?

Tags: windows, git, bash, git-bash

Is there a piece of code to unzip a file using git bash on windows? I tried unzipping with this line of code:

```
unzip somefile.zip
```

and it returns a

```
bash: unzip: command not found
```

Comment: What version of git? Unzip and gzip were included in my installation. You may have altered your path to not include them?

Comment: It's git version 2.5.1.windows.1

Comment: Do you have `unzip` in `/bin`?

Comment: `unzip` is an external command, not a `bash` built-in.  It sounds like you don't have it installed in your msys environment.

Comment: Is there a way i can install it through bash? or apt-get or something? Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 6):

Install the latest git (git-bash) from https://git-scm.com/downloads - at the time of writing it is the 2.10.0 version. It comes with unzip packaged inside as one of the tools. Check optional unix tools during setup if you already use gitbash as your go-to console.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command for window using command prompt.

`tar -xvzf filename.tar.gz`  or    `tar -xvzf filename.tgz`

execute below command for kafka.

`tar -xvzf kafka_2.12-3.3.2.tgz` or `tar -xvzf kafka_2.12-3.3.2.tar.gz`

Explanation of X,V,Z,F

> Here we’ve used the extract (-x), verbose (-v), decompress with gzip
> (-z), and file (-f) options for a complete extraction with
> decompression and detailed output

Answer (score -1):

The git bash already has unzip.

```
GE00241@0430L MINGW32 /i/UserDatastores/Private/common_words$ unzip archive.zip
Archive:  archive.zip
replace train/train/0.txt? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: n
replace train/train/1.txt? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: A
inflating: train/train/1.txt
inflating: train/train/10.txt
inflating: train/train/100.txt
inflating: train/train/1000.txt
inflating: train/train/10000.txt
inflating: train/train/100001.txt
inflating: train/train/100002.txt
```

```
git --version
git version 2.14.2.windows.1
```

It could be that you have an older version of Git. However, I am not sure if that's the issue.

Comment: This was also mentioned in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39622762/2745495), where it said unzip is available as of 2.10.

Answer (score -3):

> `sudo apt-get install unzip`
>
> `unzip your_zip_file.zip`

Works for me in Windows 10 Pro at the bash prompt.

Comment: sudo in windows?

Comment: Yes, Windows has a linux subsystem. In fact it supports multiple simultaneous subsystems.

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: The question specifically says Git Bash. WSL is off-topic.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple How so? I use Git in WSL Bash all the time, as do many people.

Comment: `git-bash` (see OP's tag) is a Windows program that emulates the Bash terminal. It's a completely different environment from WSL.

Answer (score -3):

```
tar -zxvf <filename>
```

where
`z` means (un)z̲ip,
`x` means ex̲tract files from the archive,
`v` means print the filenames v̲erbosely, and
`f` means the following argument is a f̱ilename.

Comment: As far as I know, this only works for opening gzip'd archves, like `.tar.gz` or `.tgz`, but not for zip files.